# Code to make sheets visible works from VBA Editor but not the same way with button (I made a more easy example)

Tags: excel, vba

I made a more simple example of my problem.

1. In columns A and B I have some info.
2. In column C, some rows have the name of hidden sheets.
3. I made a code that:

   - Copies Column C to Column F.
   - Removes Duplicates
   - Makes hidden sheets from Column F Visible.

The problem:
When I run the code from VBA Editor it works fine and stays on Sheet1. But when I creat a button to rund the code, it works fine but activates Sheet2.
I want to stay in Sheet1

Why the difference? any Ideas?

```
Sub showSheets()
Dim LastRowC As Integer
Dim ListOne As Range
Dim LastRowF As Integer
Dim ListTwo As Range
Dim ListThree As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Dim LastRowFF As Integer

LastRowC = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Set ReCategorizationList = Range(Cells(2, "C"), Cells(LastRowC, "C"))

ReCategorizationList.Copy Range("F2")

LastRowF = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
Set ListTwo = Range(Cells(2, "F"), Cells(LastRowF, "F"))

ListTwo.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

LastRowFF = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
Set ListThree = Range(Cells(2, "F"), Cells(LastRowFF, "F"))

    For Each Cell In ListThree
        If Cell.Value > 0 Then
            Sheets(Cell.Value).Visible = True
        End If
    Next
        
End Sub
```

Funny thing: If I run the code with the button, it activates sheet2, but if after that, I go to sheet1 again and run the code again with the button, it wont activate sheet2. The second time it will work fine.

But If I hide the sheets again and run the code again with the button, the first time it will always activate sheet2.

[image]

Comment: Found the answer here in case it serves anybody! 
Thank you @Felipe Costa Gualberto !

It's an annoying bug in Excel 2013/2016 and as far as I know, there is no fix. A workaround I use is:

Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet
'Instructions here
CurrentSheet.Activate

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here in case it serves anybody! Thank you @Felipe Costa Gualberto !
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37997386/20167855

It's an annoying bug in Excel 2013/2016 and as far as I know, there is no fix. A workaround I use is:

```
Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet
'Instructions here
CurrentSheet.Activate
```